# Coturn server - Relay is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, coturn

I am trying to setup a COTURN server for my WebRTC based application. However I am stuck with a couple of error messages that I am unable to understand, and can't find any help on them on internet.

Here are some details about the app:

- Two users log on to the app, and one of the user can share their screen with the other - so the stream is going in only one direction
- I am able to get the app to work within intranet and on some external networks. So I'm confident that the application is working fine wherever STUN mode is sufficient.
- For some of the networks the STUN candidates are constantly failing, so I need to get a TURN server to relay the stream.

I have collected some **server logs** from the server, in case someone could identify the  problem based on them:

```
handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr <IP Address>:3478, remote addr <IP Address2>:59942

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr <IP Address>:3478, remote addr <IP Address2>:59944

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

session 128000000000000096: realm <server URL> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised

session 128000000000000097: realm <server URL> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

session 128000000000000096: realm <server URL> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised

session 128000000000000097: realm <server URL> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised

IPv4. Local relay addr: <IP Address>:64306

session 128000000000000096: new, realm=<server URL>, username=<username>, lifetime=600

session 128000000000000096: realm <server URL> user <username>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success

IPv4. Local relay addr: <IP Address>:65384

session 128000000000000097: new, realm=<server URL>, username=<username>, lifetime=600

session 128000000000000097: realm <server URL> user <username>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

session 128000000000000096: realm <server URL> user <username>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success

session 128000000000000097: realm <server URL> user <username>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored

session 128000000000000096: refreshed, realm=<server URL>, username=<username>, lifetime=0

session 128000000000000096: realm <server URL> user <username>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success

session 128000000000000097: refreshed, realm=<server URL>, username=<username>, lifetime=0

session 128000000000000097: realm <server URL> user <username>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success

session 128000000000000096: closed (2nd stage), user <username> realm <server URL> origin <>, local <IP Address>:3478, remote <IP Address2>:59942, reason: allocation timeout

session 128000000000000096: delete: realm=<server URL>, username=<username>

session 128000000000000097: closed (2nd stage), user <username> realm <server URL> origin <>, local <IP Address>:3478, remote <IP Address2>:59944, reason: allocation timeout

session 128000000000000097: delete: realm=<server URL>, username=<username>
```

Here's how my **turnserver.conf** file looks:

```
listening-port=3478
#tls-listening-port=443
realm=subdomain.domain.com
server-name=subdomain.domain.com
lt-cred-mech
userdb=/etc/turnserdb.conf

cert=/home/ubuntu/certificate.crt
pkey=/home/ubuntu/qc.key
pkey-pwd=L1ght!t

no-stdout-log
Verbose
```

I am particularly concerned about the following points:

- Should I assume that since my code is working with a STUN server, it  would work with a *working* TURN server as well? Hence, the error means that the problem is with the TURN server?
- I can see a couple of errors stating 'Allocation Timeout'. Does that mean refer to any RAM/CPU/Network allocation that may be insufficient?
- Some of the requests have username portion empty '<>' rather than '', and it is followed by a '401 Unauthorized', while I have triple checked the RTCPeerConnection configurations - they do contain the username and password.
- Apart from the logs above, I have seen '438 Wrong nonce' come in quite frequently as well. I searched a bit about that, but it doesn't seem like something I can control through JS. Is it related to any server configurations?

Thanks! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a few problems in the TURN server setup I had.

- First off, we had taken it from a blog which was about two years old. As a result, the setup was also two years old - Coturn Monza. The ideal way to start would be to get the Coturn AMI (Amazon Machine Image)([Version 4.5.0.6 details](http://turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/v4.5.0.6/turnserver-4.5.0.6-amazon-aws-ec2-x86_64.txt)) and use it to setup the server. Alternatively, we should have at least taken the most recent setup through the git repository.
- Second problem was with the configurations. Even before posting the question here, we had missed to open the necessary ports on the server. Once we did that, we started getting the STUN responses, but the relay wasn't working yet.
- Third key problem was with the configurations in Turnserver.config file. We had barely gone through all configurations and after Polaris's answer  we did. The config file contains sufficient explanation for each configuration, and the problem was indeed with the configurations.
- The last problem was with the test cases. We wanted to ensure that the relay was "working", and during earlier stages of testing we had identified a particular network setup that would require relay (i.e. only STUNs would not be able to complete the request.) Eventually we learned that even TURN server would not be able to get through that setup.

  We did spend some time trying the NOSTUN mode (it's there in the turnserver.config), but due to lack of good test cases, we were never able to confirm that relay was working.

  I don't fully understand the test code on [Trickle ICE Page](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/), but I believe the results over there are reliable.

Answer (score 5):

How does your config looks like?

My working example for webRTC usage:

sudo nano /etc/turnserver.conf
->

```
listening-port=80
tls-listening-port=1133
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech
userdb=/etc/turnuserdb.conf
realm=subdomain.domain.com
server-name=subdomain.domain.com
total-quota=100
bps-capacity=0
stale-nonce
log-file=/var/log/turnserver/turn.log
no-loopback-peers
no-multicast-peers
```

sudo nano /etc/turnuserdb.conf
->Username:Passwort

You also need to allow these ports in your firewall if enabled. 
Check your server here: [Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/)

Notice, that you always need to use your ip/url with port like 123.456.789.10:80

Comment: My listening port is 3478, and accordingly the port in url is 3478. I don't have fingerprint, stale-nonce, total-quota, bps-capacity, no-loopback-peers, no-multicast-peers. I will post my current configurations in the question. Also, the server passes the test on Trickle ICE. But still there are errors when my app is using it.

Comment: Your answer isn't complete, but it helped me fix the issue. I will post an answer with the details soon. Thanks!

Comment: Do we really need a subdomain ? if yes does that mean I would have to point it to a different dedicated node for coturn

Comment: @ChangZhao I would highly recommend to split these things, also for future scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some troubleshooting tips:

- make sure you add the fingerprint option, as mentioned by Polaris
- try just using a static username and password for now, e.g.:

  user=username:test
- then include this in your PeerConnectionConfig:

  {'url': 'turn:yourserver.com:3478', credential: 'test', username: 'username'}
- Use the "WebRTC Network Limiter" chrome extension to force WebRTC to use the TURN server.
- Comment out the cert and pkey for now.

Comment: Thanks, what's the role of cert and pkey? Earlier I had noticed that the server wasn't even working properly in STUN mode when I left out the cert and pkey.

Comment: I think it might be for TLS. I don't use it in my config.